# Current location on maps is not accurate. didUpdateLocations iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps, location

I am working on app where I need exact current location. The current location works fine when I am outdoors in iOS app. But when I am inside a building the current location is inaccurate. Its 100 meter away from my exact location.

The setting for location manager are as follows:

```
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
 locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
 locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

And I am calling this function for location updates:

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
    self.updatedLocation = location    
}
```

The current location works fine on Android devices in buildings.
One thing that I have observed that when I open the Apple Maps and Google Maps app the current
location is the same as I am getting in my app but they have a light blue circle showing that you could be anywhere around that area.

Is there anyway I could improve the current location when I am inside a building?

Any help would be appreciated.

First image is screenshot from iOS where current location is inaccurate and the second image is screenshot from Android device where the location is precise.

[image: Screenshot from iOS.]

[image: Screenshot from Android.]

Comment: GPS signals do not penetrate into buildings very well. If this is your building and your app you can add indoor mapping data to your app but if you are talking about buildings in general there is nothing you can do about this

Comment: @Paulw11 ah okay. Is there any possible way of knowing through my current location in iOS that if I am inside a building or not? It currently shows me outside the building even though I am inside.

Comment: Duplicate of [ios google maps accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955800/ios-google-maps-accuracy)

Comment: You can check the `horizontalAccuracy` of the updated location to know how accurate the location data is. You can also get inaccurate locations when you are outside but between tall buildings.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am getting the issue with tall buildings. The value of horizontalAccuracy is 5 even though the current location is completely incorrect for the image that I have shared. It shows me on the flyover or sometimes on the underpass but never in the building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed this problem as well, especially with find my iphone, when i'm in a building the location of my phone is always 50-100 m away i didn't know why.

Currently I'm working on an app that require the exact location, so one thing you can do is check the `horizontalAccuracy` property on the `CLLocation` that you're being returned. If this is above a certain threshold then you could throw away the result and wait for a more accurate one. If it is a number of miles out then I would expect the accuracy figure to be quite large. It's most likely using a cell site to determine location rather than GPS, and the margin of error would be much greater.

Here it is an example from my own application:

```
    func requestUserLocation(){
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Then on `didUpdateLocations` function I'll do the check

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

manager.desiredAccuracy = 1000 // 1km accuracy

if locations.last!.horizontalAccuracy > manager.desiredAccuracy {
    // This location is inaccurate. Throw it away and wait for the next call to the delegate.
    print("i don't want this location")
    return;
}
// This is where you do something with your location that's accurate enough.
guard let userLocation = locations.last else {
    print("error getting user location")
    return
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.

Comment: I understand that it could give me more accurate results. But the issue is that I am not even getting my current location accurate.

Comment: Let me add the locations images in my question, you can see the difference is too much. If there is any possible way to minimize that difference, please let me know?

Comment: GPS is still never perfect, you may get anywhere from 5 to 100m accuracy so i don't think there is much to do however i think the place where you are, you are getting this things maybe another user won't, and as i saw your photos i'm having the same thing exactly i'm in a bulding and it shows me that i'm in a road exactly as you lol and it's in find my iphone so don't worry about it too much

Comment: I will go with your solution at least it helps me improve accuracy. Thanks.